# Knife project not working

Tags: modeling, objects, knife-tool

In some simple cases such using the default Monkey as the object to project, the resulting cut looks nothing like the monkey. Note the selected cube only has only been cut around the monkey's eyes, not the entire object.
[image: knife project with the default monkey]
Trying with other primitives results in this error

> No Other selected objects found to use for projection

I know that I have both objects selected.

Comment: Suzanne is non-manifold, so it just gets the eyes. Knife project is designed to work with flat 2D meshes as the projection object, so I think the overlapping faces confuses it. Collapsing a sphere into a flat circle and removing doubles makes it work as a projection object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because *knife project* [only uses wire or boundary edges](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide#Knife_Project):

> Knife projection is a non-interactive tool where you can use objects
>   to cookie-cut into the mesh rather than hand drawing the line.
>
> This works by using the outlines of other selected objects in
>   edit-mode to cut into the mesh, resulting geometry inside the cutters
>   outline will be selected.
>
> **Outlines can be wire or boundary edges.**
>
> To use Knife Project, in 'object' mode select the "cutting object"
>   first then shift select the "object to be cut". Now tab into edit mode
>   and press "knife project".

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

A boundary edge is an edge with nothing connected on one side, e.g.:

[image]

The primitives, being manifold objects, do not have wire or boundary edges.

Suzanne partially works because it is non-manifold (the eyes are disconnected). The two circles that you get by projecting Suzanne are the boundary edges around the eyes.

[image]

The error message is a little bit strange though.

Comment: If Blender documentation could be as clear as your answer...

Comment: Inspired by this answer to [contribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/about/index.html#getting-started) to the Blender docs.. see changes [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html)

Comment: @JJones Cheers! BTW, barring a bit of Z-fighting, projection of  edges internal to the silhouette can work if you _Delete > Faces Only_  https://imgur.com/a/v4wIO5k

Comment: @RobinBetts  Hmm... maybe instead of giving that error  knife-project should use the face-less version of the object?  Would the "z-fighting" complicate that? Better left as-is?

Comment: @JJones yup.. just twigged gandalf was on it, anyway.